# calling a method from another namespace and displaying it's result to a textbox from a different namespace

Tags: c#, methods, instance

I have this method which is from the namespace: `GraphiQS.Core.Models`

```
  public static float ComputeLength(PointF start, PointF end, float scale)
    {
        var a = end.X - start.X;
        var b = end.Y - start.Y;
        var result = (float) Math.Sqrt(a * a + b * b);
        return result * scale;
    }
```

and I want the result of this method to be displayed at the textbox from the namespace: `GraphiQS.UI.Tests.Forms`. What shall i do? I tried making an instance of it but I don't know what to do next.

Comment: What do you mean of namespace!??! do you want to mention to assembly?

Comment: the package where the method is located sir

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the two namespaces exist in the same assembly, you can access this method by adding a using statement to the source file that you’re trying to call the method from.  This will look like this:

using GraphiQS.Core.Models;

This would go with the rest of your using statements. After this, you can call your method from the body of your code like this:

{classname}.ComputeLength(someStart, someEnd, someScale);

{classname} refers to the class that your method belongs to.  It’s unclear if you’re trying to call the method directly without a reference to the class (which wouldn’t work).  I’m confused by your statement about trying to create an instance. Since ComputeLength is a static method, you don’t have to create an instance of the class it belongs to in order to use it.  If the namespace exists in your assembly, my guess is that you’re having one of the following problems:

1. You’re trying to call the method directly without referencing the class as shown above
2. You’re missing a using statement

If the two namespaces are not in the same assembly, then you might be missing a reference to the assembly that contains the GraphiQS.Core.Models namespace. Double check and make sure you’re referencing all necessary assemblies.

Comment: i already put a using statement but i still cant call the computelength method

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say that you can’t call the method?  How are you trying to call it?  It would be helpful if you could show the code you’re using to try to call it.  Is the class that the method belongs to also public?

Comment: yes it is public and this is the code i was trying to use to call the method to another class   private void _btn3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
            Length length = new Length();
            
        }

Comment: There's no method call in the code you provided.  In your code, you're creating an instance of a class named Length.  Where/how are you trying to call your static ComputeLength method?  It's hard to help you without some more context.

Comment: can i call a static method or not??because i really don't know what to do next after making an instance of the class length

Comment: Yes. I show how to call a static method in my answer. If the name of the class that ComputeLength belongs to is Length, then you would call it like this:  Length.ComputeLength(someStart, someEnd, someScale);  Maybe your issue is that you're trying to call a static method on an instance of the class instead of the class itself.  In your example, "Length" is the class and "length" is an instance of that class.  Trying to call a static method on the instance "length" won't work (because it's not an instance method).

Comment: yeah that is what i did i created the instance of the class length because thought it's okay to use that to call the instance of the ComputeLength method hahaha,thank you for helping dude now it's clear to me what to do

Comment: Good! Is the answer I provided accurate? If so, can you accept?